# Paste the text from clipboard char by char

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a paste function that simulate a write "character by character" inside an input field, but my code doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
^+V::                                            
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
    SendRaw, %clipboard%
}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying too hard. Send command will already send key by key of whatever content you may pass into it.

```
; Use this in case of delaying each key press.
; SetKeyDelay, Delay
^+V::
    SendRaw, %clipboard%
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^v::
ClipBucket5 := Clipboard
ClipBucket5 := RegExReplace(ClipBucket5, "\r\n?|\n\r?", "`n")
Loop, parse, ClipBucket5 
{
    SendRaw, %A_Loopfield%
    Sleep, 100
}
return
```